# R: Rvest - got hidden text i don't want

Tags: r, rvest, rselenium

I'm doing webscraping to this web:

```
http://www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat40536/Climatizacion?navAction=push
```

I just need the information from the products: "brand", "name of product", "price".

[image]

I can get that, but also i get the information from a banner with similar products by other users. I don't need it.

But when i go to the source code of the page, i can't see those products. I think it's been pulled through javascript or something:

[image]

**QUESTION 1:** **How to block this information when doing the web scraping?** 
This adds products that i don't need. But can't see this part in the source code.

**QUESTION 2: When extracting prices "precio1", i get this as first element: *`"\n\t\t\t\tSubtotal InternetS/. 0"`* I can't see that in the code source neither. How to not scrape it?**

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
#start RSelenium
checkForServer()
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()

#navigate to your page
remDr$navigate("http://www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat40536/Climatizacion?navAction=push")


page_source<-remDr$getPageSource()


Climatizacion_marcas1 <- html(page_source[[1]])%>%
        html_nodes(".marca") %>%
        html_nodes("a") %>%
        html_attr("title")


Climatizacion_producto1 <- html(page_source[[1]])%>%
        html_nodes(".detalle") %>%
        html_nodes("a") %>%
        html_attr("title")


Climatizacion_precio1 <- html(page_source[[1]])%>%
        html_nodes(".precio1") %>%
        html_text()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Staying close to your approach, this will do it:

```
library(rvest)
u <- "http://www.falabella.com.pe/falabella-pe/category/cat40536/Climatizacion?navAction=push"
doc <- html(u)

Climatizacion_marcas1 <- doc %>% 
  html_nodes(".marca")[[1]] %>%
  html_nodes("a") %>%
  html_attr("title")

Climatizacion_producto1 <- doc %>% 
  html_nodes(".detalle") %>%
  html_nodes("a") %>%
  html_attr("title")
```

The "\n\t\t" etc. comes from the parsing of the html. Apparently, there are carriage returns and tabs in there. A simple solution is:

```
Climatizacion_precio1 <- doc %>% 
  html_node(".precio1") %>%
  html_text() %>% 
  stringr::str_extract_all("[:number:]{1,4}[.][:number:]{1,2}", simplify = TRUE) %>% 
  as.numeric

Climatizacion_precio1
[1] 44.9
```

This, in fact, picks the number from the string (thus also removing the "S/.". In case you want the "S/." to stay, you can do the following:

```
Climatizacion_precio1 <- doc %>% 
  html_node(".precio1") %>%
  html_text() %>% 
  gsub('[\r\n\t]', '', .)

Climatizacion_precio1
[1] "S/. 44.90"
```

**EDIT**
Here is an alternative approach, using `XML` and `selectr`. This will get the info for all of the items on the page in one go.

```
library(XML)

clean_up <- function(x) {
  stringr::str_replace_all(x, "[\r\t\n]", "")
}

product <- selectr::querySelectorAll(doc, ".marca") %>% 
  xmlApply(xmlValue) %>% lapply(clean_up) %>% unlist

details <-   selectr::querySelectorAll(doc, ".detalle a") %>% 
  xmlApply(xmlValue) %>% 
  unlist

price <- selectr::querySelectorAll(doc, ".precio1") %>% 
  xmlApply(xmlValue) %>% lapply(clean_up) %>% unlist

as.data.frame(cbind(product, details, price))
      product                  details      price
1       Imaco  Termoventilador NF15...  S/. 44.90
2       Imaco  Ventilador de 10"  I...     S/. 69
3       Imaco  Ventilador Imaco de ...     S/. 89
4      Taurus  Recirculador TRA-30 ...     S/. 89
5       Imaco  Termoventilador ITC-...    S/. 109
6        Sole Termo Ventilador ElÃ©...     S/. 99
7      Taurus  Ventilador TVP-40 3 ...     S/. 99
8       Imaco  Estufa OFR7AO 1.500 ...    S/. 129
9      Alfano  Ventilador Recircula...    S/. 139
10     Taurus  Ventilador TVC-40RC ...    S/. 139
11      Imaco  Ventilador Pedestal ...    S/. 149
12     Alfano  Ventilador Orbital 1...    S/. 149
13 Electrolux  Ventilador  de Mesa ... S/. 149.90
14     Alfano  Estufa Termoradiador...    S/. 159
15     Alfano  Ventilador Pared 18"...    S/. 169
16      Imaco     Termoradiador OFR9AO    S/. 179
```

You would normally probably want to do some initial cleaning of the results.

Comment: Thanks. This is intresting, so you just scrap it and then remove it with regex. About the banner at the bottom, I could also remove the last 4 elements (there are 4 products in the banner). You say, satying close to your approach, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there are EOL (end-of-line) and tabs in the page itself, so you won't be able to scrape it without them. You could experiment with using different parsers, but this does the trick nicely as well.
The "staying close" comment was meant to convey that I only needed to make tiny adjustments to your code to make it work. Of course there are additional ways to do this, but `rvest` has become quite popular, Alternatives woudl include the `XML` and `xml2` packages.

Comment: Well, since you ask, I have added an alternative approach to my answer. Hope it is useful.
Feel free to upvote and accept the answer if it helps you with your problem.

Comment: you deserve the upvote. Thanks. But i still want to know: 1.- why i got the "products from the banner" at the end of the page. 2.- What does the regex in your answer do? Thanks!

Comment: The regex replaces the unwanted \n, \r, \t with an empty character `""`, which removes them from from the string.