# How to use rvest to web crawling correctly?

Tags: r, web-crawler, rvest

I try to web crawl this page http://www.funda.nl/en/koop/leiden/ to get the max page it could show which is 29. I followed some online tutorial and  located where 29 is in the html code,  wrote this R  code

```
url<-  read_html("http://www.funda.nl/en/koop/leiden/")

url %>% html_nodes("#pagination-number.pagination-last") %>% html_attr("data-
pagination-page") %>% as.numeric()
```

However, what I got is `numeric(0)`. If I remove `as.numeric()`, I get `character(0)`.

How is this done ?

Comment: Try using this instead: `url %>% html_nodes("a.pagination-number.pagination-last")`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that both your identification of the html and your parsing of the html are wrong. To easily find the name of a CSS id, you can use a chrome extension called Selector Gadget. In your case, it also requires some parsing, accomplished in the `str_extract_all()` function.

This will work:

```
url <-  read_html("http://www.funda.nl/en/koop/leiden/")

pagination.last <- url %>% 
  html_node(".pagination-last") %>%
  html_text() %>% 
  stringr::str_extract_all("[:number:]{1,2}", simplify = TRUE) %>%
  as.numeric()

> pagination.last
[1] 29
```

You might find this other question helpful as well: [R: Rvest - got hidden text i don't want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30541445/r-rvest-got-hidden-text-i-dont-want)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it seems I can not reproduce the results. I copy the code and it generates NA. All packages and Rstudio are up to date.  In this step url %>% html_node(".pagination-last") %>% html_text(). It already generates NA, what happened? Did I miss something?

Comment: try `> str(url)` and see if it outputs this: 
List of 2
 $ node:<externalptr> 
 $ doc :<externalptr> 
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "xml_document" "xml_node" 
If it doesn't then something is going wrong with the initial step of reading the html

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with the same issue and this worked for me:

```
> url = "http://www.funda.nl/en/koop/leiden/"
> last_page <-
+   last(read_html(url) %>% 
+          html_nodes(css = ".pagination-pages") %>%
+          html_children()) %>% 
+   html_text(trim = T) %>% 
+   str_extract("[0-9]+") %>% 
+   as.numeric()
> last_page
[1] 23
```