# Can't crawl numeric data with rvest packages

Tags: html, r, web-crawler, rvest

I try to crawl the data from the naver news(Korean news platform).
It is easy to craw news itself, however, I failed to crawl the numbers of the comments.

Here's the picture of the developer tool of google chrome.
What I want to crawl is the number between  and  (which is '695')
This is the address of the news(https://news.naver.com/main/ranking/read.nhn?rankingType=popular_day&oid=003&aid=0008965477&date=20181217&type=1&rankingSectionId=100&rankingSeq=1)

[image]

I tried;

```
url_test <- "https://news.naver.com/main/ranking/read.nhn?rankingType=popular_day&oid=003&aid=0008965477&date=20181217&type=1&rankingSectionId=100&rankingSeq=1"

test_news <- read_html(url_test)
test_news %>%
  html_nodes(".content") %>%
  html_nodes(".article_body") %>%
  html_nodes(".end_btn") %>%
  html_nodes("._reactionModule") %>%
  html_nodes(".u_likeit_list")
good <- reaction[1] #why 0?
good %>% html_text()`
```

and the return value is "0"

I fount one thread dealing similar issue ([How to use rvest to web crawling correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346556/how-to-use-rvest-to-web-crawling-correctly)) and tried it, however, it doesn't work for me.

What I tried is as below

```
test_news %>%
  html_node(".u_likeit_layer") %>%
  html_text() %>% 
  stringr::str_extract_all("[:number:]{1,2}", simplify = TRUE) %>%
  as.numeric()
```

and

```
test_news %>%
  html_nodes(css = ".u_likeit_layer") %>%
  html_children() %>% 
  html_text(trim = T) %>% 
  str_extract("[0-9]+") %>% 
  as.numeric()
```

all codes return '0' while I want crawl numbers btw spans.
I also tried Xpath, CSS to navigate the address, but failed!!

Thanks in advance for your help! ;)
Have a great day.

Comment: `robots.txt` of that site has `User-agent: *` `Disallow: /` so you're doing something you shouldn't be doing.

Comment: @hrbrmstr thanks a lot!